# Access and see deleted questions - Feature request

Tags: support, feature-request, deleted-questions

I wanted to search for ♯ http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12334/are-these-two-questions-on-gcd-of-powers-of-a-and-b-duplicates and
  ♯ http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12330/any-question-or-answer-on-the-main-site-about-this-lemma.  I tried
♯ http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/85100
but nothing is here. Additionally I tried http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/13302/85100.

All in all, after multifold comments and searches by Martin Sleziak kindly, only moderator Alex Becker found them. By reason of time and effort, I thence request that all users can access and see their own deleted answers and questions.

Comment: You can see your *own* deleted questions and answers on your profile. Other people's in general you won't even be able to find again (which is sort of the point).

Comment: IIRC it should be listed with your other questions. But it's been a long time since I hit 10k rep, so I'm not quite sure what you can see.

Comment: From the link you mentioned, it seems that you have searched in [your profile on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/85100/dwayne-e-pouiller?tab=questions) and not [your profile on main](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/85100/dwayne-e-pouiller?tab=questions).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes. This missing question is on Meta, not on main..

Comment: I have tried to enter your user id [into this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.math/query/124865/my-posts-in-reverse-chronological-order) and I have also tried [googling your posts on meta](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Dwayne%20E.%20Pouiller%22+site%3Ameta.math.stackexchange.com). I did not find any questions which are not shown on your profile page. (By which I mean: I did not find any deleted questions.) You might try to improve the query in google search, if you remember some parts of the post or some relevant keywords.

Comment: Is it [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12334/are-these-two-questions-on-gcd-of-powers-of-a-and-b-duplicates) or [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12330/any-question-or-answer-on-the-main-site-about-this-lemma)?

Comment: @AlexBecker: Yes. How'd you find it?

Comment: Mod superpowers.

Comment: The feature request from the second paragraph is now implemented for 10k+ users: [Is there any way to see my deleted questions or answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13948)